# Android images on drawable-mdpi are beeing used on 10.1in tablet and 5.1

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I need to develop my game for 5.1in devices to 10.1in devices...On 5.1, the imageviews look perfect, but on 10.1, they are too small. Unfortunally, it looks like eclipse picks the same image for both 10.1 devices and 5.1: It´s the image i put on drawable-mdpi folder.
Is there any chance it would use the image on drawable-xxhdpi folder when the device is 10.1in? What should i do to make my images bigger on bigger android devices?

Answer (score 0):

You want to provide different resources based on the screen size in dp, not the dpi - see the docs on [supporting multiple screeen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). This is because you can have xxhdpi displays on 4" devices, in which case your resources would be very small for the display.